# Using batch file to type hostname into website

Tags: batch, microsoft-edge

So I'm trying to automate installing our remoting software. We have about 1000 PC to install it on and would be nice to not have to hand type everything.

Currently I have it launching and signing in but need it to look at the PC's host name and then type it into edge. I'm very new to scripting so keep that in mind. Also if there is a better way to do this then any advise is welcome.

Here is what I have so far. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

start microsoft-edge: 

timeout /t 1

%SendKeys% "{enter}"

Timeout /t 1    
                        
Used to type in my info. Then will send me Duo Prompt.      

                                            
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"             
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{}"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

timeout /t 10

start microsoft-edge:

timeout /t 2

%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"

%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"
%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"
%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"
%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"
%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"
%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"

%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"


pause

@end

// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Where exactly do you have to type the hostname? In the address bar?

Comment: What Windows are the client machines running?

Answer (score 1):

```powershell
<!-- :
@echo off
"%windir%\system32\wScript.exe" "%~dpnx0?.wsf" "hOsTnAmE" & goto :EOF
:: --> 
<job><script language = "vbscript">
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run """msedge.exe"" ""google.com""", 9
WScript.Sleep 700
For i=1 To 9
    If i>8 Then
           WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Else
           WshShell.SendKeys (WScript.Arguments(0))+"{ENTER}"
        End If
    Wscript.Sleep 700
Next
For i=1 To 19
    If i<9 Then
           WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        ElseIf i<15 then
           WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
        Else 
           WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    End If
    Wscript.Sleep 700
Next
</script></job>
```

---

Your question doesn't make it clear what you mean with all these `{TABs}`, `{downs}`, `{ETCs}`, but I suspect you're not understanding that `sendkeys`/[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) can send 1 or more keys, regardless of whether it's one character at a time or a chain/string...

Please edit your question and make it clear what you want to send by keys and where your hostname goes, if by argument, or by environment variable (`set` or `setx`)..

**Obs.:** The code will give you an idea of ​​using hybrid bat with [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) instead of [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript)

Answer (score 0):

Well the part of getting the hostname is easy:

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('hostname') do set HostName=%%a

Next you would start Microsoft Edge with the hostname:

start msedge.exe "%HostName%"

If all the client machines run Windows 10 maybe you could consider using curl instead of VBS script to send input to a local ou remote site...

Comment: Its a combo of win 7 and win 10 with a few win 8 and 11. I was able to get the stations host name but I am wanting the script to type out the hostname. So want the script to pull the host name and type it in. It already launches and signs me into the website and moves the cursor where I need it to.

Comment: echo %hostname%...? %sendkeys% "%Hostname%"..

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past, but using [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) instead.  I actually made a video about it a short while back...[here](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/harrisonchu88_ahk-autohotkey-activity-6926804524640743424-6X-j) it is.